# How to instantiate a class that requires DOM with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, coffeescript, puppeteer

I want to instantiate a class called `DataBinding` that uses `document.querySelector` inside a *CoffeeScript* file. To achieve this, I'm using *Puppeteer* to create the *DOM* environment. However, inside `page.evaluate`, the code didn't recognize the class `DataBinding`. I'm performing this to test the `DataBinding` class. I tried to run the following code, but it didn't work:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import { DataBinding } from // correct path

browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new', executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"});
page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto 'http://127.0.0.1:9000';

await page.evaluate(() =>
    data_binding_instance = new DataBinding();
) 

await browser.close();
```

1. I'm running a blank `index.html` page just to create the DOM.
2. This code is transpiled by *esbuild* to generate a *.js* file.
3. I'm running the transpiled code with `node test_data_binding.js` (where *test_data_binding.js* is the transpiled file).

I tried a lot of things, such as using `page.exposeFunction` to pass a function to the *Puppeteer* context that returns a `DataBinding` class, but it didn't work.

Comment: `evaluate` runs the callback in the browser, not in Node, so it won't have access to classes you've defined in Node. `exposeFunction`, on the other hand, runs in Node context, meaning it can't use `document.querySelector`. Given that the whole setup is [rather unusual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), I suggest explaining what you're trying to accomplish, then it will be possible to present an alternative design that makes sense and achieves your underlying goal.

Comment: You may want to use `addScriptTag` to inject the build js into the browser, then call functions from an `evaluate` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @ggorlen! I want to create a unit test for the `DataBinding` class, which is used in the front end of my project. Because it depends on the `document`, my idea was to use _Puppeteer_  to instantiate it, but I encountered the problem that you mentioned...